# 111: Connection refused while connecting to upstream

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to duplicate [my .NET Core Linux environment from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71170660/deploy-net-6-app-with-multiple-projects-to-linux-elastic-beanstalk-server-from) to have 2 environments, and the logs say

> Now listening on: http://[::]:5000

which makes me think it is working, but the requests get this error:

> (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
> 172.31.44.219, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.47.124"

And it times out. I believe everything is the same, while the initial environment is working perfectly fine. I created this one without "configuring more options" so it is not part of a VPC etc but neither is my initial environment. What should I be checking? I have viewed some answers on here for this issue but no fixes worked. For example, I commented out `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` but still have the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have noticed that EB creates and attaches a security group, and it listens on port 80, not 5000. I am leaving this here as it might be helpful for someone else (aka my future self).